# Plotly-Python: How to change the background color for title text?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, subplot

I'm trying to change the background colour for the title in plotly to something like the below:

[image]

Plotly Code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    subplot_titles=("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
              row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[300, 400, 500], y=[600, 700, 800]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[4000, 5000, 6000], y=[7000, 8000, 9000]),
              row=2, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=500, width=700,
                  title_text="Multiple Subplots with Titles")

fig.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to change the background colour of the title text using plotly?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no support yet for this feature based on this discussion https://community.plotly.com/t/apply-the-background-colour-for-titlle/36900

Comment: The only thing I can do is change the text color. `subplot_titles=("<span style='color:red;'>Plot 1</span>", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"))` This will make the text color red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, there does not seem to be a direct way to set the subplot title backgrounds, however, the closest I could get to what you were looking for was to create an [annotation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/annotations/#layout-annotations-items-annotation-bgcolor) at the top of each chart, and set it's background accordingly.

Now you could perhaps generate some form of formula to calculate the best position of each annotation, however, I just did it by eye - as a proof of concept. In general, the x-coord is the middle x-point of each chart, and the y-coord is just above the maximum y-value of each chart.

Please let me know what you think:

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
              row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[300, 400, 500], y=[600, 700, 800]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[4000, 5000, 6000], y=[7000, 8000, 9000]),
              row=2, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=500, width=700,
                  title_text="Multiple Subplots with Annotated Titles",
                  annotations=[dict(
                     x=2, y=6.3,            # Coordinates of the title (plot 1)
                     xref='x1',
                     yref='y1',
                     text='*                  Plot 1 Title                *',
                     bgcolor = "#2b3e50",     # dark background
                     font_color = "#FFFFFF",  # white font
                     showarrow=False),
                   dict(
                     x=30, y=73,            # Coordinates of the title (plot 2)
                     xref='x2',
                     yref='y2',
                     text='*                  Plot 2 Title                *',
                     bgcolor = "#2b3e50",     # dark background
                     font_color = "#FFFFFF",  # white font
                     showarrow=False),
                   dict(
                     x=400, y=830,          # Coordinates of the title (plot 3)
                     xref='x3',
                     yref='y3',
                     text='*                  Plot 3 Title                *',
                     bgcolor = "#2b3e50",     # dark background
                     font_color = "#FFFFFF",  # white font
                     showarrow=False),
                    dict(
                     x=5000, y=9290,          # Coordinates of the title (plot 4)
                     xref='x4',
                     yref='y4',
                     text='*                  Plot 4 Title                *',
                     bgcolor = "#2b3e50",     # dark background
                     font_color = "#FFFFFF",  # white font
                     showarrow=False)])

fig.show()
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]